# Translating a WordPress theme

Tags: localization, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to translate [The Buffet Framework](http://www.zy.sg/the-buffet-framework/) with the help of [Codestyling Localizazion](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/). But somehow the theme simply doesn't use my translation.

Is there something I forgot to consider? Any experience with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your wordpress directory, find wp-config.php then edit

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
```

to your language, example below:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'id_ID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your theme have the line …

```
load_theme_textdomain(domain-name);
```

… in its functions.php? `domain-name` should match your text domain.

Comment: Yea, it does: `// Load theme localization
load_theme_textdomain('buffet');`